# Objective C: Touch Point Distance

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am having troubles with the drawing app that i am making.

In portrait its touch point is ok, the line follows the right touch point but when i switch the orientation to landscape here's what happened:

the red X mark is the touch point but the line starts in different point.

[image]

how am i gonna solve this problem??

here's my code:

on viewDidLoad:

```
    touchView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgimg.png"]];
    [touchView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    [self.view addSubview:touchView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:touchView];

    touchMoved = 0;

    touchView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

on touchesMoved:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [touchView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0f);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    touchView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats the view heirachy like?

If the touches are in a different view or parent view you will most likey need to call the convertPoint: method of the UIView to get the correct location for the point.

If you can post your view heir achy I might be able to help more

Cheers,

Michael